# Trait that, when mixed in, turns a class into a final class

Tags: scala, traits

Is it possible, in Scala, to have a trait that makes the class into which it is mixed in `final`?

I need to prevent inheriting from a class if this class mixes in a trait, but I'm not sure if this is possible. Maybe I need a macro for that.

Or a trick, like defining a `final` member in the trait to avoid mixing that trait twice, but this is not what I need to achieve.

Example:

```
trait MyTrait
class A extends MyTrait
class B extends A
def myFun[T <: MyTrait](t: T)
```

This function not only requires `T` to implement/mixin `MyTrait`, but suppose it contains logic that doesn't work if `T` is a base class and what is actually passed in as `t` is a child of `T`. For example `myFun[A](new B)`.

Clearly this is a corner case but maybe there's a way to ensure/specify that the `t` passed as parameter must be exactly of type `T` and not one of its children. I don't know if this is possible, and that would be the best solution.

The closest thing I could find is making sure `T` is final and the best would be writing something in `MyTrait` that enforces it.

So my question.

Alternatively, how can I make sure `T` is a case class?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Can you elaborate a bit better on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You might find this gist by Miles Sabin interesting: https://gist.github.com/milessabin/ace99b2feaa6e4e8822cda08d79cb91e

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. Macros won't help either: you can't trigger a macro by extending something, only by an annotation or by calling a method (as far as I know).

Comment: I may use an annotation instead of a trait for the same purpose

Comment: You would need to annotate the class you want to make final, in which case it's easier just to make it final then and there.

Comment: Well not exactly, that annotation may have another meaning and, in addition to that, make the class final. But I prefer actual code than playing with macros.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach:

```
trait MyTrait
class A extends MyTrait
class B extends A

def myFun[T](t: T)(implicit ev: T =:= A) = ()
defined function myFun
@ myFun(new A)

@ myFun(new B)
Main.scala:61: Cannot prove that cmd2.B =:= cmd1.A.
myFun(new B)
     ^
Compilation Failed
```

It's a bit different from what you ask, since it has nothing to do with the trait. It just enforces you can only pass type `A` into that function, not its children.

Comment: But `A` is a specific type, I need it generic. I need to make sure that `t` is exactly an instance of `T`, whatever `T`, or whatever `T <: MyTrait`.